# Not able to Find the Installed Windows phone 8.1 App from Windows phone 8.0 App

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

We have Two apps in the store, one is Windows phone 8.0 app and other one is Windows phone 8.1 RT app.

I want to launch the WP8.1 app from WP8.0 app.

In WP8.0 app, I am using following line to find the packages of the same publisher

```
Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackagesForCurrentPublisher()
```

Even though Wp8.1 app is already installed in the device, above code is not listing the WP8.1 app.  After finding the package, I want to launch the WP8.1 app by calling `package.Launch(string.Empty);`

But above line is not finding the wp8.1 app.  Both app has same publisher "CN=xxxx...".

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: If you add another 8.0 app, can you see that? I think the API might only handle Silverlight apps.

Comment: is the 8.1 version a wp8.1 RT or silverlight?

Comment: Target App is WP 8.1 RT app